# Double click windows to minimise in Lion?

Tags: windows, mouse, preferences

Before upgrading to Lion I was able to double-click the header bar of windows to minimise the windows. Since upgrading I only seem to be able to minimise by clicking the yellow `-` button.

Is this a setting that I'm missing?

Comment: What apps have you tried this with? It works fine for me in all my apps...

Comment: Safari is the one I'm noticing the most, just tested Twitter for Mac and it's the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > General. Check "Double-click a window's title bar to minimize".

[image: Minimize]

Comment: Interesting that this got unchecked when you upgraded. I'm always surprised by which settings get lost :/